# how to call function in children Tabs NativeBase when change tab

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I have one scrollable tab component that have 4 tabs in it.
I want to call function in any child when change tab with swipe or click on tab.
this is my code in render function :

```
<Tabs
        initialPage={0} 
        ref={(tabView) => { this.tabView = tabView}}
        renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab />}
        onChangeTab={(e)=>{this.onChangeTab(e)}}>
          <Tab heading="Tab1">
            <oneScreen name={"tab1"} ref={this.tab1} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab2" >
            <twoScreen name={"tab2"} ref={this.tab2} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab3">
            <threeScreen name={"tab3"} ref={this.tab3} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab4">
            <fourScreen name={"tab4"} ref={this.tab4} navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
```

this is my change tab function :

```
onChangeTab({i,from,ref}) {
// const tab = ref.ref.current    
//   tab.fetchData(this.state.changeText)
```

}

please help me about that

Comment: Hello can you tell me what is ````{this.tab1}```` of each Tab item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for get children of tabs

```
onChangeTab({i,from,ref}) {
  //get child
  const tab = ref.props.children

  //call function in child
  tab.fetchData()
}
```